# object literal. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type (no object spread)

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow works correctly with exact types in the below case:

```
type Something={|a: string|};
const x1: Something = {a: '42'};        // Flow is happy
const x2: Something = {};               // Flow correctly detects problem
const x3: Something = {a: '42', b: 42}; // --------||---------
```

… however Flow also complains at the following:

```
type SomethingEmpty={||};
const x: SomethingEmpty = {};
```

Message is:

```
object literal. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
```

This is not the same case as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42968014/274677) as no spread is used.

Tested with the latest `0.57.3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Object` literal without properties is inferred as an unsealed object type in Flow, this is to say you can add properties to such an object or deconstruct non-existing properties without errors being raised:

```
// inferred as...

const o = {}; // unsealed object type
const p = {bar: true} // sealed object type

const x = o.foo; // type checks
o.bar = true; // type checks

const y = p.foo; // type error
p.baz = true; // type error
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8C+BuAUKSsAOiKARgIYBOAXDFGQK4Cmqm240MAHoSAHQBmIIdDAD0w6gE889GMAAW9YAGsImHqTKEaDIaIlSZ8pSpa4Y4wnj4CdYqJOn0yZEGUyXSAL0116NvQ6cXIA)

To type an empty `Object` literal as an exact type without properties you need to seal it explicitly:

```
type Empty = {||};
const o :Empty = Object.seal({}); // type checks
```

[Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAogtmUUC8UDeAfDBfA3AKAGMB7AOwGdgpioAueREFKAeQCMArCQ4AOnIgBDADYAKNNgCUuIA)

Comment: Note that `seal` no longer works. The current workaround is `Object.freeze({})`. See [reference](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2977#issuecomment-390613203).